# Calculate average of an array and insert in another array

Tags: java, arrays, average

How can I calculate the average of an array, and insert it in another array and print that in the console. 
For example, I have an array of size 100, and I wanna calculate the average of the numbers in the array and then insert in in an array of size 5.

Comment: If you're calculating one average why a second array of size 5? Also is this homework?

Comment: I don't wanna calculate one average, I need to calculate 5 averages from the array of size 100. and no it's not homework. just something I can't seem to get done for my program.

Comment: So you'll compute the average for the first 20 elements then the next 20 and so forth?

Comment: yeah, something like that. I am currently in a huge blank and have nothing to get me started :/

Comment: *"just something I can't seem to get done for my program"*.  Really?  And why is that?  What difficulties did you find when you tried to write the code yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        float averages[] = new float[5];
        int aLotOfNumbers[] = new int[100];

        // Initialize the numbers to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 99
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            aLotOfNumbers[i] = i;
        }

        // Compute the averages by summing groups of 20 numbers and dividing the sum by 20
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            float runningSum = 0.0f;
            for(int j=0; j<20; j++)
            {
                runningSum += aLotOfNumbers[i*20 + j];              
            }
            averages[i] = runningSum / 20.0f;
        }

        // Print the 5 average values
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Average[" + i + "] = " + averages[i]);
        }
    }
}
```